# trigonometry integral

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve this integral and I know that the solution should be $\frac{7}{2} tan\frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{6}tan^3\frac{x}{2} +C$. However I'm way off, where do I miss in my calculations?

$\int \frac{3+4cosx}{(1+cos x)^2} dx = [tan \frac{x}{2} = t, cos x = \frac{1 - t^2}{1 + t^2}, \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{2}{1+t^2}] = \int \frac{3+4\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)}{\left(1 + \frac{1-t^2}{1-t^2}\right)^2}\times \frac{2}{1+t^2} dt = \int \frac{\frac{6(1+t^2)+8(1-t^2)}{1+t^2}}{\frac{1-2t^2+t^4}{1+t^2}}dt = \int \frac{-2t^2+14}{t^4-2t^3+1} dt = 14\int \frac{1}{(t-1)^2(t+1)}dt - 2 \int \frac{t^2}{(t-1)^2(t+1)} = 14 \int \frac{1/4}{t+1} + \frac{1/2}{(t-1)^2}-\frac{1/4}{t-1} dt - 2\int \frac{1/2}{(t-1)^2}+\frac{3/4}{t-1} + \frac{1/4}{t+1} dt = \frac{7}{2}\left(ln \left|\frac{t+1}{t-1}\right|\right)-\frac{7}{t-1} + \frac{1}{t-1} - \frac{6}{4} ln (t-1) - \frac{1}{2} ln (t+1)= + C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you messed up on the third step, where you forgot to add $1$ to the cosine.  Thus, the answer should be

$$\int dt \frac{3(1+t^2)+4 (1-t^2)}{2} = \frac12 \left (7 t-\frac13 t^3\right )+C$$

Comment: but $\frac{2}{1+t^2}$ still leaves me with one 2 too much to get to $\int dt \frac{3(1+t^2)+4(1-t^2)}{2}$. I get $\int dt 3(1+t^2)+4(1-t^2)$

Comment: @iveqy: You get a $2$ above and a $2^2$ below.

Answer (score 0):

Another way : $$\int\frac{3+4\cos x}{(1+\cos x)^2}\ dx=\int\frac{4(1+\cos x)-1}{(1+\cos x)^2}\ dx$$

$$=4\int\frac{dx}{1+\cos x}-\int\frac{dx}{(1+\cos x)^2}$$

Now, $\dfrac1{1+\cos x}=\dfrac1{2\cos^2\dfrac x2}=\dfrac{\sec^2\dfrac x2}2$

$\dfrac1{(1+\cos x)^2}=\dfrac1{(2\cos^2\dfrac x2)^2}=\frac14\left(1+\tan^2\dfrac x2\right)\sec^2\dfrac x2$